# How to declare an array of arrays in JS?

Tags: arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an array containing a dynamic number of sections, each of which containing a dynamic number of items.

So it's an array of arrays, but how to declare that? The code below doesn't work:

```
const sections = []
sections[0].push(sectionItem)
sections[0].push(sectionItem)
sections[1].push(sectionItem)
sections[1].push(sectionItem)
sections[1].push(sectionItem)
sections[2].push(sectionItem) // 'sectionItem' is different each time of course
```

What's the correct way of accomplishing this?

Comment: I think what you're after is a multidimensional array

Comment: `sections` is an empty array, so `sections[n]` will be undefined. perhaps you mean `sections[0] = sectionItem` if sectionItem is an array? or `sections[0] = []; sections[0].push(sectionItem)` to first store an array at the index and then push to it.

Comment: You should really give a more realistic and concrete example, as it depends on what the item is you want to push. Edit your question and make a runnable snippet using the toolbar, so that when we run it we see the problem you encounter.

Comment: `const sections = [ [sectionItem, sectionItem], [sectionItem, sectionItem, sectionItem], [sectionItem] ];`? Notice the inner arrays.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you may do like;

```
sections = ( Array.isArray(sections[n]) ? sections[n].push(sectionItem)
                                        : sections[n] = [sectionItem]
           , sections
           );
```